# Как обработать токен от reCAPTCHA v3 на react?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recaptcha

```
import { GoogleReCaptchaProvider, GoogleReCaptcha } from "react-google-recaptcha-v3";

const App = () => {
  <div className="passwordRecovery">
    <GoogleReCaptcha onVerify={token => console.log(token)} />

    <div className="passwordRecoveryWrapper">
      <div
        className="mainFormPasswordRecovery"
        onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}
        onSubmit={this.onSubmit}
      >
        <h3>Восстановление пароля</h3>
        <p>
          Введите e-mail, который вы указывали при регистрации. Мы отправим вам
          письмо с инструкцией по восстановлению пароля
        </p>
        <p className={this.state.Email ? "dirty" : ""}>
          <MaskedInput
            mask={emailMask}
            id="login"
            type="text"
            name="login"
            value={this.state.Email}
            onChange={this.onEmailChange}
          />
          <label htmlFor="login" className="textLabel">
            {" "}
            E-mail{" "}
          </label>
        </p>

        <p className="recoverPasswordBtn">
          <input
            type="submit"
            value="Восстановить пароль"
            onClick={this.onSubmit}
          />
        </p>
        <p className="alternate">
          <Link to="/">Я вспомнил пароль</Link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <FooterNavBar />
  </div>
}
```

В гугловской инструкции сказано, что в ответе должно быть свойство score, по которому определяется степень "человечности" пользователя. На реакте получаю токен, но не понятно, что с ним делать дальше.

Привожу код формы с рекапчей.

Comment: Приложите Ваш код к вопросу, без него сложно будет

Comment: Компоненты обернуты в ReCaptchaProvider                                 
       <GoogleReCaptchaProvider reCaptchaKey="...">
  <Router/>
 </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>                                                                                             В одном из компонентов получаю токен                                                     
<GoogleReCaptcha onVerify={token => console.log(token)} />

Comment: Токен и статистику по посещениям получаю.

Comment: Нажмите кнопку "править" на вопросе, и оформите свой код. Из того что Вы привели у меня возникли другие вопросы, а если бы был весь код сразу, то я бы знал какой пакет Вы используете, как Вы его используете, как получаете токен и другие данные.

Comment: Добавил код. Использую пакет "react-google-recaptcha-v3": "^0.1.5"

Answer (score 0):

Я не уверен что можно что то подсказать про свежий пакет (v0.1.5) который не имеет стабильной версии.

Совет посмотрите в сторону других решений, ну или связывайтесь с разработчиком через [Github Issues](https://github.com/t49tran/react-google-recaptcha-v3/issues)

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, исчерпывающее http://pravosleva.ru/article/recaptcha-v3

Вам нужна серверная часть для получения токена и проксирования в гугл. Например, простейший Express сервер, который обработает ваш запрос с первым (клиентским) ключом и временным токеном от Гугла, полученным посредством, к примеру, `react-recaptcha-v3` (не важно, какую юзаете библиотеку) и использующий второй (серверный) ключ. Короче, там та еще заморочка )

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]